# Form field with an explanatory pop up in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form in which I want to create a button like feature to explain the content of the form field. Something like this:

[image]

The question mark is the button itself, and when the user taps it, it shows a dialog or pop up (doesn't need to be like in the picture, but similar) which contains some text.

I was investigating about suffix property, that allows me to do something like that but not in the label text, as label text needs a string, not a widget, and its mandatory for this project to do this in the label text.

Here is the current code of that form field:

```
DropdownSearch<
            Map<String, dynamic>>(
          dropdownDecoratorProps:
              const DropDownDecoratorProps(
            dropdownSearchDecoration:
                InputDecoration(
              floatingLabelBehavior:
                  FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
              labelText: "Crop",
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: 'Select crop',
            ),
          ),

          //Dropdown search items
        )
```

Comment: Try using tooltip widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add the button that you want to use to display the explanation, then you can wrap it a Tooltip widget like this:

```
                      Tooltip(
                                message:
                                    'Explanation here',
                                child: Icon(
                                    Icons.info,
                                  ),
                              )
```

The Tooltip is triggered by default upon a longPress but you can change this to be onTap, you can also change the duration that the message appears for, by doing the following:

```
                      Tooltip(
                                triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                                showDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                                message:
                                    'Explanation here',
                                child: Icon(
                                    Icons.info,
                                ),
                              )
```

Comment: But how can i display the tooltip at the right of the formfield label?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct solution for this, you can just play with the propereties of Tooltip 'verticalOffset' by giving it a negative value until it's centered, and add a 'margin' so the message can be displayed on the right; 'margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),'. But for sure this is not the best solution, the Tooltip is meant to be displayed above or below the button. But you can always try some packages like this that can do it for you if the Tooltip is not enough: https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip